# Feature Matching in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, surf, camera-calibration, matcher, flann

I have two binary images obtained by background subtraction in which I have white circles at the points of my interest. I converted them into keypoints and obtained SURF descriptors. Then, when I use a FlannBased Matcher (even tried BFMatcher) to match the corresponding points, all the points in Image 1 are getting matched to a single point in Image 2.

I need help in understanding where I might be going wrong. I am suppose to use these matched points as the matches for finding Fundamental matrix.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post example images, or links to them. And preferably your code as well.

Comment: I am not convinced that SURF can really work on binary images. If you need the fundamental matrix between both images, why not converting the images to grayscale and use them directly (instead of applying background subtraction)?

Comment: I initially started by applying SURF to gray scale images. Since, the images were from two opposite corners of the room, I could not find good matches and hence my Fundamental matrix was not as expected. So, I thought it might be easier to find matches when only few keypoints( centers of blobs in background subtracted images) are present.